# Why react use angular brackets in rendering the component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to the react as my background is ruby, so maybe it look a silly or noob question.
i come to the article
"Every component must begin with a capital letter. And once a component is declared, it can be written and used very similarly to an HTML element." and also this
"To use this component in your application, use similar syntax as normal HTML: "

```
class Car extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {color: "red"};
  }

 render() {
    return <h2>I am a {this.state.color} Car!</h2>;
  }
}

root.render(<Car color="red"/>);
```

we have a car component created using class component so my question here is Why we use angular bracket here for creating instance of Car class. is this a syntax of creating instance of class in react.
Or
To use this component we have to use similar syntax as HTML. why?

Comment: You can find the answer by reading any doc about React. Maybe you could start with the JSX part https://en.reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html

Answer (score -1):

React uses angular brackets () in rendering an element as a result it permits you to incorporate the element as a JSX part. JSX may be a syntax extension for JavaScript that permits you to write down HTML-like code in your JavaScript files. it's not obligatory to use JSX with React, however, it's a preferred alternative, as a result, it makes it easier to grasp the structure of your elements and the way they relate to the DOM.

To render an element in React, you'll use the ReactDOM.render() methodology and pass it to the element you wish to render further as a DOM part.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

const MyComponent = () => <h1>Hello, World!</h1>;

ReactDOM.render(<MyComponent />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

The MyComponent operation is wrapped in angular brackets () and passed to the ReactDOM.render() methodology as a JSX part. This tells React to treat the operation as an element and render it within the DOM part with the id of the root.

Comment: This answer is helpful but not super clear. A JSX component is a collection of HTML markup + JS functionality authored in JavaScript. React is a JS library that allows us to [author and inject these components into a page in the context of a virtual DOM](https://reactjs.org/docs/rendering-elements.html) that is continually updating as data inside the components changes. `render()` is a React utility that attaches this HTML + JS into the page and manages updates to its state. Finally, in React you can have class-based or functional components. Most now use functional components.

Answer (score -2):

Hopefully this helps. Before React we needed an index.html File and had to call your javascript.js file within your HTML[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dca4y.png). example: in HTML, if we wanted to select a Button in javascript and add an onClick event we had to call the button but be specific as possible, so we had to add a class,ID, etc... Import your button to your javascript file like car= document.getElementById("car1")
and then add a onclick event. as you can see this can be exhausting. worst part is you cant add HTML in your Js file, so no

tags,  etc.. so the way to make things easier in HTML is adding brackets. React allows you to use HTML and Js syntax.
in your example: return

### I am a {this.state.color} Car!

;
we are telling React we have h2 from HTML but anything within { } is Javascript. as you can see React just makes easier to use HTML and javascript in the same file

Comment: This response is technically factually incorrect. React and Angular are still doing all these things we had to do in vanilla HTML and JavaScript, they are just doing it under the hood, as a part of the MVC framework library. React and Angular still generate an HTML file that loads one or more JS bundles. You can see this if you run a build on your project and inspect the `./dist` or other output location.